# RelativeLayout - button in wrong place

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using a RelativeLayout for the first time and have positioned two buttons as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flybut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/flybut" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/jumpbut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/flybut"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/jumpbut" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the flybut is positionsed 10dp from the left of the screen, and virtically in the centre of the screen. The jumpbut is also positioned 10dp in from the left of the screen and 10dp above the flybut. It all looks exactly as expected in the eclipse GUI, but at run time the jumpbut is in the wrong place. It is correctly 10dp in from the left, but it is jammed up againt the very top of the screen. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: make sure that the parent occupies the entire height of the screen, if it is defined as wrap_content then the buttons will be centered only in the space they occupy...

Comment: @Mikel: Not sure I understand... I've just edited the OP to show the entire xml.. does that reveal my error?

Comment: 'android:orientation="vertical"' shouldn't be used here for RelativeLayout. It's for LinearLayout.

Comment: you have what I said ok, ignore the comment...

Comment: Remove the `+` in `android:layout_above`. This may not solve your problem but it's a common practice, since you are referring to a resource id that's already been created.

Comment: Vertical removed, plus sighn removed... no change :-(

Comment: Did you try to set the `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` property of the `jumpbut`?